# Can I get the SID("Oracle Session Id") through a OCI Function?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

There is an example that simply uses a OCI function to execute a query.

```
skip..

  text *sql = (text *)"SELECT empno, ename FROM emp";
  int id;
  text pad[4000];

  strcpy(username, "scott");
  strcpy(password, "tiger");
  strcpy(dbname, "orcl");

  OCIEnvCreate(&env, OCI_DEFAULT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  OCIHandleAlloc(env, (dvoid *)&err, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, 0, 0);

  if (r = OCILogon2(env, err, &svc, username, strlen(username), password, strlen(password), dbname, strlen(dbname), OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS)
  {
    checkerr(err, "OCILogon2", r);
  }

  if (r = OCIStmtPrepare2(svc, (OCIStmt **)&stm, err, sql, strlen(sql), NULL, 0, OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS)
  {
    checkerr(err, "OCIStmtPrepare2", r);
    goto clean_up;
  }

...skip


  if (r = OCIDefineByPos(stm, &def, err, 1, &id, sizeof(id), SQLT_INT, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS)
  {
    checkerr(err, "OCIDefineByPos", r);
    goto clean_up;
  }

  if (r = OCIDefineByPos(stm, &def, err, 2, pad, sizeof(pad), SQLT_STR, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS)
  {
    checkerr(err, "OCIDefineByPos", r);
    goto clean_up;
  }

  if (r = OCIStmtExecute(svc, stm, err, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS)
  {
    checkerr(err, "OCIStmtExecute", r);
    goto clean_up;
  }

...skip
```

I want to get the SID of the session that executes the above query.

I thought I could get it through "OCIAttrGet".. 
tried to find the manual, but it failed...

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via a query:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') from dual;
```

This is often useful in queries like:

```
select unique client_driver from v$session_connect_info where sid = sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

Comment: Thanke you...
Is there any way to get it without querying?